# vb.net excel to datatable

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I have an excel file that has 3 sheets,
I was able to read those sheets into 3 different variables as datatable.
is there any way to run sql query on any datatable
please check the last line (my invention code)
here is my code:

```
  Dim table_customers As DataTable
    Dim table_materials As DataTable
    Dim table_movement As DataTable

    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [accounts$]", MyConnection)
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    table_customers = DtSet.Tables(0)
    MyConnection.Close()
    MsgBox("customers ok")


    Dim sql = "select cusomer_name from  '" & table_customers & "' where condition inner join  '" & table_materials & "' on .....  "
```

Comment: If the data is already available in a Excel workbook, you may consider using an external table rather than using VB program.

Comment: i have very complex query to perform,
I need to have my own custom query with inner join and group by and other complex issues,
my query is about 5 lines of sql code